# Insert into distinct columns from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

How to insert into a temp table that is all ready created inside of a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_1]
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        col1 INT,
        col2 INT,
        col3 VARCHAR(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO #Temp
       EXEC [spSelection] @ID

    ..do stuff
    ..do stuff
    ..do stuff

    SELECT * FROM #temp
END
```

The problem I am having is, I will use this stored procedure (`spSelection`) in the future and if I change this stored procedure to get more columns for a different stored procedure, then `Report_1` will fail.

So I need a way to dynamically create the table or be able to only select distinct columns from the output of `exec [spSelection] @ID` or have `Report_1` be able to read from a temp table created in `spSelection`.

I have tried to use a global and that will not work because it can be used by other stored procedure at the same time, if I create a dynamic SQL.

```
@sql ='
    create table #Temp(
    col1 int,col2 int,col3 varchar(50)
    ) ' exec sp_executesql @sql
```

I can not access the `#temp` table outside of the quotes

Comment: It's a **STORED** procedure - as in a procedure that is **stored** inside your SQL Server - not a "storage procedure" ...

Comment: Then create a new stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a stored procedure for selecting results, you can create a view and use `SELECT INTO` clause to dynamically create temp table at run time.

You can not use stored procedure in select statement.

Comment: This is a possible solution as long as the SP isn't composed of complex logics that can't be solved with a simple `SELECT` (this is the view's limitation).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to change your SP to make the insert ***inside*** the SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [spSelection]
AS
BEGIN

    -- Validate that your temporary table was created (the insert will fail otherwise)
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('The table #Temp must be created before executing this SP', 16, 1)
        RETURN
    END

    ..do stuff
    ..do stuff
    ..do stuff

    INSERT INTO #Temp (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3)
    SELECT
        /*Columns*/

END
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_1]
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        col1 INT,
        col2 INT,
        col3 VARCHAR(50)
    )

    EXEC [spSelection] @ID -- Will insert into #Temp

    ..do stuff
    ..do stuff
    ..do stuff

    SELECT * FROM #temp
END
```

This approach will fail if you eventually add new columns to the `#Temp` table and insert them inside the SP without updating the `CREATE TABLE` in every SP that calls it.

There is no definitive solution here, please read [this excellent paper](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) about all possible ways to share data between SP, with pros and cons of each (the solution I posted here is listed as **4. Using a table**).